# Mongoid: filtering an embedded collection by sub-sub-documents multiple fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, moped

I am a beginner in mogo and mongoid.
I it possible to filter sub-documents collection by a sub-sub-documents multiple fields ($elemMatch)? I'm trying to make a parametrized scope for an embedded collection.

Set up:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String, default: ''

  embeds_many :versions, class_name: self.name, validate: false, cyclic: true
  embeds_many :flags
end

class Flag
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :text, type: String
  field :state, type: Boolean
end
```

Typically now i want to filter my versions within single product by flags state and name:

`Product.first.versions.where('$elemMatch' => {'flags.text' => 'normalized', 'flags.state' => true})` dosn't work.

Either don't work:

```
Product.first.versions.elem_match(flags: {text: 'normalized', state: true})
Product.first.versions.where(:flags.elem_match => {text: 'normalized', state: true})
Product.first.versions.where(flags: {'$elemMatch' => {text: 'normalized', state: true}})
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: by the docs : http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#docs, This : Product.first.versions.elem_match(flags: {text: 'normalized', state: true}) should work, but try also Product.first.versions.where(flags => {'$elemMatch' => {text => 'normalized', state => true}}). Have you tried to make the query in the mongoshell? Would help much if you could provide the right (that you likely to use in mongoid) query in mongoshell format.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this in mongo shell.. According to log Mongoid makes single query to fetch the whole document `Product.first` and then emulates query on an embedded collection, without actually hitting the database.
However something like `Product.first.versions.where('flags.text' => 'normalized')` works just fine, returning an array with corresponding versions. It only doesn't work when i want to filter the embedded collection by multiple sub-sub-documents field

Comment: Corresponding issue in mongoid/mongoid https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3097